# How to pick first ul tag after h4 tag skipping any other tag between them, with Nokigiri?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping

I'm trying toy get the first ul tag after the tag h4 and skipping the div tags:

```
<h4>
 <a>
  "Q1. some text"
 </a>
</h4>
<ul>
 <li>answer</li>
 <li>answer</li>
 <li>answer</li>
</ul>

<h4>
 <a>
  "Q2. Some text"
 </a>
</h4>
<ul>
 <li>answer</li>
 <li>answer</li>
 <li>answer</li>
</ul>

<h4>
 <a>
  "Q2. Some text"
 </a>
</h4>
<div>WITH OTHER INFO THAT i DON'T WANT</div>
<ul>
 <li>answer</li>
 <li>answer</li>
 <li>answer</li>
</ul>

<h4>
 <a>
  "Q2. Some text"
 </a>
</h4>
<div>WITH OTHER INFO THAT i DON'T WANT</div>
<ul>
 <li>answer</li>
</ul>
<ul>
 <li>DONT NEED THIS</li>
</ul>
<ul>
 <li>DONT NEED THIS</li>
</ul>
```

And this code is mostly like this a bunch of times so I need to pick just the first ul tag after the h4 and skipping the div tags with nokigiri and ruby.

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri.HTML(DATA)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use either the `following-sibling` or `following` axis, and specify the first matching `ul`:

```
doc.xpath('//h4/following-sibling::ul[1]')
```

Comment: That solve my issue thanks.